# ayuda con codigo en c

Tags: c, programación-funcional

me podrian ayudar con mi codigo, la edad y el numero de integrantes sale mal.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct estructura 

{

char nombre[30], dir[40], sangre[10];
int edad[3], integ[2];
};

struct estructura bene;


main()

{

printf( "Escribe tu nombre: " );
scanf( "%s", &bene.nombre );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe tu edad: " );
fflush( stdin );
scanf( "%d", &bene.edad );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe tu direccion: " );
scanf( "%s", &bene.dir );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe el numero de personas de tu familia: " );
scanf( "%d", &bene.integ );
system("cls");
printf( "Escribe tu tipo de sangre: " );
scanf( "%s", &bene.sangre );
system("cls");  
printf( "Nombre: %s \n", bene.nombre);
printf( "Edad:  %d \n", bene.edad );
printf( "Direccion: %s \n", bene.dir );
printf( "Integrantes:  %d \n", bene.integ );
printf( "Tipo de sangre: %s \n", bene.sangre );

return 0;
```

}

Comment: tu problema esta cuando declaras `int edad[3], integ[2];` que intentas hacer con eso? Si lo declaras así `int edad, integ;` ya funciona.

Comment: muchas gracias, estoy iniciando en programacion, pense que con eso se declaraba el numero de caracteres para la variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char nombre[30], dir[40], sangre[10];
int edad, integ;
```

prueba dejando esa parte asi

Comment: Es decir que a edad e integrantes déjalos simplemente como variables enteras

Comment: gracias, asi quedo, ahora tengo otras cuestiones jejeje